# Why can't I manipulate inputted list (list = [input()]) ? If possible, how?

Tags: python

I am creating a sequence identifier and I want a shorter code by manipulating the list. However:

```
#This is possible:
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
A = list[1] - list[0]
print(A)

#This is not possible:
list = [input()]
A = list[1] - list[0]
print(A)
```

Comment: The result of `input()` is a _string_; you can either use some expression to convert it to a list of integers `[int(x) for x in input().split(",")]`or `eval()` valid Python (though [beware `eval` is very dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice))

Comment: **list** is a built-in type, you should not use it as a variable name, although python allows you to do.

Answer (score 1):

`[input()]` is only one (**string**) element, so `list[1]` doesn't exist to be used in subtraction.

If you want a list of 5 user-entered **integers**, you would use

```
[int(input()) for _ in range(5)]
```

And press enter after each value

Or for space-separated values - `[int(x) for x in input().split()]`

Comment: Can I also use the file = open(name, 'r') command?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to?